# When I run syncdb with django does it specify collation settings for mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Plain and simple. I have a new django project. I add some models and specify proper mysqldb settings in settings.py. I run syncdb. Are collation settings determined by my MySQL install or does syncdb have some say over this?

Comment: django does not provide a way to do this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings

> you set the collation by directly manipulating the database tables;
>   Django doesn't provide a way to set this on the model definition.

I guess, this answers your question, plain and sweet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but in most cases you probably want utf-8.

If it's the case, you specify character set when you create MySQL database:

```
CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;
```